# Split sentence by space mixed up my index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm facing some problem while trying to send text to some spelling API.

The API return the corrections based on the words index, for example:

sentence:

> "hello hoow are youu"

So the API index the words by numbers like that and return the correction based on that index:

```
  0     1   2   3
hello hoow are youu
```

API Response that tell me which words to correct:

```
1: how
3: you
```

On the code I using split command to break the sentence into words array so I will be able to replace the misspelled words by their index.

```
string.split(" ");
```

My problem is that the API trim multiple spaces between words into one space, and by doing that the API words index not match my index. (I would like to preserve the spaces on the final output)

Example of the problem, sentence with 4 spaces between words:

> Hello      howw are youu?

```
      0   1 2 3 4   5    6   7
    hello          hoow are youu
```

I thought about looping the words array and determine if the element is word or space and then create something new array like that:

```
indexed_words[0] = hello 
indexed_words[0_1] = space
indexed_words[0_2] = space
indexed_words[0_3] = space
indexed_words[0_4] = space
indexed_words[0_5] = space
indexed_words[0_6] = space
indexed_words[0_7] = space
indexed_words[1] = how
indexed_words[2] = are
indexed_words[3] = you?
```

That way I could replace the misspelled words easily and than rebuild the sentence back with join command but the problem but the problem that I cannot  use non-numeric indexes (its mixed up the order of the array)

Any idea how I can keep the formatting (spaces) but still correct the words?

Thanks

Comment: someone gave you the correct answer but he deleted it!:))
use regex: string.split( / +/g )

Comment: nope, there's a solution belove, using **.match**, I can see it.

Comment: View this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40718423/1556386

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

```js
var str = "Hello      howw are youu?";

var words = str.split(" "); 

// Getting an array without spaces/empty values
// send it to your API call
var requestArray = words.filter(function(word){
    if (word) {
        return word;
    }
});


console.log("\nAPI Response that tell me which words to correct:");
console.log("6: how\n8: you");

var response = {
  "1": "how",
  "3": "you"
}

//As you have corrected words index, Replace those words in your "requestArray"
for (var key in response) {
    requestArray[key] = response[key];
}

//now we have array of non-empty & correct spelled words. we need to put back empty (space's) value back in between this array 
var count = 0;
words.forEach(function(word, index){
    if (word) {
        words[index] = requestArray[count];
        count++;
    }
})

console.log(words);
```

Correct me, if i was wrong.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The problem is the API not count space as a word, so the API response in your example will be var response = {
  "1": "how",
  "3": "you"
}

Comment: And I would like in the final result to keep the multiple spaces, so my problem is to match the API response word index to my word index that contain also the spaces

Comment: @Shai I updated my answer. please check it once and reply me back

Answer (score 0):

Please review this one:
For string manipulation like this, I would highly recommend you to use `Regex`
Use online regex editor for faster try and error like here `https://regex101.com/`. 
here I use /\w+/g to `match` every words if you want to ignore 1 or two words we can use `/\w{2,}/g` or something like that.

```js
var str = "Hello      howw are youu?";
var re = /\w+/g
var words = str.match(re); 
console.log("Returning valus")
words.forEach(function(word, index) {
  console.log(index + " -> " + word);
})
```

**Correction**

Just realize that you need to keep spacing as it is, please try this one:
I used your approach to change all  to `space`. create array for its modified version then send to your API (I dunno that part). Then get returned data from API, reconvert it back to its original formating string.

```js
var ori = `asdkhaskd asdkjaskdjaksjd     askdjaksdjalsd a  ksjdhaksjdhasd    asdjkhaskdas`;

function replaceMeArr(str, match, replace) {
  var s = str,
    reg = match || /\s/g,
    rep = replace || ` space `;
  return s.replace(reg, rep).split(/\s/g);
}

function replaceMeStr(arr, match, replace) {
  var a = arr.join(" "),
    reg = match || /\sspace\s/g,
    rep = replace || " ";
  return a.replace(reg, rep);
}

console.log(`ori1: ${ori}`);
//can use it like this 
var modified = replaceMeArr(ori);
console.log(`modi: ${modified.join(' ')}`);

//put it back
var original = replaceMeStr(modified);
console.log(`ori2: ${original}`);
```

Comment: That's a good solution, but you should explain what your solutions does. Not simply write some code down.

Comment: That solution is not solve my problem, because in the final result I would like correct the misspelled words but also to keep the multiple spaces.

Answer (score 0):

in that case you have very simple solution:L

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var OriginalSentence="howw      are you?"
      var ModifiedSentence="";
      var splitstring=OriginalSentence.split(' ')
       $.each(splitstring,function(i,v){

            if(v!="")
             {
                //pass this word to your api and appedn it to sentance
                 ModifiedSentence+=APIRETURNVALUE//api return corrected value;


               }
            else{

                      ModifiedSentence+=v;
                 }

        });
        alert(ModifiedSentence);


     });
```

Comment: I'm not controlling the API code, so I can modify only the client side code. In the final result I would like to correct the misspelled words and also keep the multiple spaces (I want to keep the user text formatting)

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](https://jsfiddle.net/hilalbaig/uL2o4wdp/) JSFiddle
, Happy coding :)

```js
//
//  ReplaceMisspelledWords
//
//  Created by Hilal Baig on 21/11/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Baigapps. All rights reserved.
//

var preservedArray = new Array();
var splitArray = new Array();

/*Word Object to preserve my misspeled words indexes*/
function preservedObject(pIndex, nIndex, title) {
  this.originalIndex = pIndex;
  this.apiIndex = nIndex;
  this.title = title;
}

/*Preserving misspeled words indexes in preservedArray*/
function savePreserveIndexes(str) {
  splitArray = str.split(" ");
  //console.log(splitArray);
  var x = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < splitArray.length; i++) {
    if (splitArray[i].length > 0) {
      var word = new preservedObject(i, x, splitArray[i]);
      preservedArray.push(word);
      x++;
    }
  }
};


function replaceMisspelled(resp) {
  for (var key in resp) {

    for (var i = 0; i < preservedArray.length; i++) {
      wObj = preservedArray[i];
      if (wObj.apiIndex == key) {
        wObj.title = resp[key];

        splitArray[wObj.originalIndex] = resp[key];

      }
    }
  }

  //console.log(preservedArray);
  return correctedSentence = splitArray.join(" ");
}

/*Your input string to be corrected*/
str = "Hello      howw are youu";
console.log(str);
savePreserveIndexes(str);
/*API Response in json of corrected words*/
var apiResponse = '{"1":"how","3":"you" }';
resp = JSON.parse(apiResponse);

//console.log(resp);
/*Replace misspelled words by corrected*/
console.log(replaceMisspelled(resp)); //Your solution
```